How to Expand Allocated WSA Disk Storage
I have installed Magisk on WSA (with Google Apps) version of WSA and using it to download media. However, I am continuously hitting the error of no disk space available in WSA. It seems WSA apps storage is maxed on 128 GB.


I have also written a script that cleans logcat logs, where there were times they exceeded 300gb+ of logs stored. So that's not my issue.
del /q C:\Users\saud\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\diagnostics\logcat\*.log

I just can't figure out a way to force WSA to allow apps to use more disk space.
